# Search and replace content

Tags: regular-expression, perl, search, replace

```
PIN A
1 1:3 0:8
0 0:0

PIN B
1 1:0
0 0:0
Z Z:0

PIN C
1 1:3 0:8
0 0:0
Z Z:0
```

I would like to change the content on PIN A & PIN C only without affecting PIN B to

```
0 0:3
Z 0:3
```

Can't seem to find a way to replace without affecting the contents in PIN B using universal
search and replace method:

```
perl -i -pe 's/0:0/0:3/g;' text
perl -i -pe 's/Z:0/Z:3/g;' text
```

Desired Output:

```
PIN A
1 1:3 0:8
0 0:3

PIN B
1 1:0
0 0:0
Z Z:0

PIN C
1 1:3 0:8
0 0:3
Z Z:3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the paragraph mode with `-00` where records are delimited by empty lines and do something like:

```
perl -00 -i -pe 's/\b[0Z]:\K0\b/3/g if /^PIN (A|C)\b/' text
```

(or just `if /^PIN [AC]\b/` for single letter PINs).

Or:

```
perl -00 -i -pe 's/\b[0Z]:\K0\b/3/g unless /^PIN B\b/' text
```

A more generic approach is to record the *current PIN* in a variable, and do the substitution when that variable has the value you want:

```
perl -i -pe '
  if (/^PIN (.*)/) {
    $pin = $1;
  } else {
    s/\b[0Z]:\K0\b/3/g unless $pin eq "B";
  }' text
```

That `s/\b[0Z]:\K0\b/3/g` replaces the trailing 0 in `[0Z]:0` (where `\K` is used to mark the start of what is to be `K`ept (and thus replaced) from the match) with 3 provided they're preceded and followed by word `b`oundaries to avoid it matching `0:0` inside `10:02` for instance. That won't stop it matching inside `1:0:0.3` though as `:` and `.` are not *word characters* so there is a *word boundary* between `:` and `0` and between `0` and `.`.